# Как отобразить булеты строк в richedit?

Tags: c++, winapi

Поддерживает ли richedit "внешние" булеты, можно ли ими управлять? (ну как в notepad++ кругляшок возле нумерации строк) Пример создания контрола ниже.

```
LoadLibrary(TEXT("Msftedit.dll"));
 HWND hwndEdit= CreateWindowEx(0, MSFTEDIT_CLASS, TEXT("Type here"),
    ES_MULTILINE | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | WS_TABSTOP, 
    x, y, width, height, 
    hwndOwner, NULL, hinst, NULL);
```

Comment: Задать можно через SetParaFormat PFN_BULLET (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-setparaformat) или вы хотите чтобы булеты были на внешнем контроле, а ричэдит контрол кидал уведомления при достижении булета? может проще дернуть весь контрол из исходников npp?)

Comment: Я хочу что б булеты были с лева от текста, и каждую строку можно было отметить булетом или снять его. Строки разделены возвратом каретки. Как в notepad++ или как в VisualStudio. На внешнем или внутреннем - что б слева в одну колонку....

Comment: у notepad++ открытый исходный код, можно, как вариант, там подглядеть как реализовано